# Store each parsed value of JSON into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, parsing

I'm working on the Array in C#, as following code below, the uricontent is a List in which each string contains one JSON value, I could parse the content, however, I want to have one other array or List to store each parsed value, in the example below, rooms variable can store each time one JSON parsed value, now I wish to store those parsed values in one array.

> ```
>         int i = 0;
>
>         while (uricontent.Count != 0)
>         {
>             var rooms = JObject.Parse(uricontent[i].ToString())
>             ["rooms"]
>             .Select(x => new
>             {
>                 roomID = (string)x["room_name"],
>                 Name = WebUtility.HtmlDecode((string)x["room_name"]),
>                 Price = PriceHelper.Convert((string)x["discountedTotal"]),
>                 Currency = (string)x["currency"],
>                 Occupan = (int)x["adult"]
>             }).ToArray();
>
>
>
>             i++;
>         }
> ```
>
> rooms {<>f_*AnonymousType11[1]<>f*_AnonymousType11[]
>
> > > > > > [0]  { roomID = "Superior 1st floor", Name = "Superior 1st floor", Price = 207.4, Currency = "EUR", Occupan = 2 }

As indicating above, the rooms overwrite the data in each iteration, how can I store those values in one other array like 
     [1].....
     [2].....
....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. `SelectMany` concatenates all of the `IEnumerables` generated by the inner `Select` statements, and returns them as a single `IEnumerable`, which can then be converted into an array:

```
var rooms = uricontent
    .SelectMany(
        uriContentElementJson =>
        {
            JObject uriContentElement = JObject.Parse(uriContentElementJson);
            return uriContentElement["rooms"].Select(
                room => new
                {
                    RoomID = (string)room["room_name"],
                    Name = WebUtility.HtmlDecode((string)room["room_name"]),
                    Price = PriceHelper.Convert((string)room["discountedTotal"]),
                    Currency = (string)room["currency"],
                    Occupant = (int)room["adult"]
                });
        })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: hi @ChrisMantle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015735/parsing-html-page-into-parent-child-object-c-sharp Could you have a look at this question link ? Im facing some selectmany stuffs too Thanks