# Parsing HTML Page into Parent-Child Object C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack, fizzler

I'm parsing the html page, and I'm new to this kind of parsing, could you suggest me the idea to parse following html [image]

HTML Code : http://notepad.cc/share/CFRURbrk3r

for each type of room, there are list of sub rooms so I wish to group them as Parent - Childs into the List of Objects. then later we can access to each of those childs.

this is the code as far as I could do but without adding to the Objects, besides Fizzler is there any other parser I can do in this case.

```
var uricontent = File.ReadAllText("TestHtml/Bew.html"); 
var html = new HtmlDocument(); // with HTML Agility pack         
html.LoadHtml(uricontent);                      
var doc = html.DocumentNode;                      
var rooms = (from r in doc.QuerySelectorAll(".rates")                             
             from s in r.QuerySelectorAll(".rooms")                           
             from rd in r.QuerySelectorAll(".rate")                           
             select new 
             {                  
                Name = rd.QuerySelector(".rate-description").InnerText.CleanInnerText(), 
                Price = r.QuerySelector(".rate-price").InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
                RoomType = s.QuerySelector("tr td h2").InnerText.CleanInnerText()   
             }).ToArray();
```

Comment: The code you posted works and it returns the right stuff what else do you need?

Comment: Is the issue your actually having, is now that you have the proper data your having trouble manipulating it?

Comment: @verdesrobert : it repeats the subrooms if you notice, anyways I fixed the code with HTMLAgilityPack, could you have a check too? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Personally, I wouldn't use an Array.  I would use a `List`.  The implementation of a `List` should allow you to add particular nodes into particular positions and grouped accordingly.

Then you could simply:

- Loop (foreach)
- Find
- Sort
- Select

Which would allow you to quickly filter through the content.  Since each list item is stored.  Some [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

---

**Update:**

Another item I forgot to mention, the *Html Agility Pack* can do the following:

- Grab a particular node / element.
- Grab a Parent and all subsequent Children node / elements.

It can also grab remote or local pages.

---

I would actually download the *Html Agility Pack* from Nuget.  It is incredibly powerful and robust, it will more than likely make it even easier to scrub the desired data.  You can download it by following these steps:

- Go to *Tools*
- Go to *Nuget Package Manager*
- Select *Package Manager Console*
- Open the *Package Manager Console* in lower left of Visual Studio if it didn't open.
- Type the following command `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`.

A great example can be found from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).

The premise is simple:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// Map the document to the Html Page.
document.Load(filePath);

// If you would rather do it through Xml String, should you require it.

if (document.DocumentNode != null)
{
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
     if( bodyNode != null)
     {
           // Do something with bodyNode.
     }
}
```

This example shows the syntax, but it should be far easier to grab particular nodes out of the page and manipulate it accordingly with the `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Hopefully this points you in a better direction.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, I have finished the parsing with HTML AgilityPack, but still I dont get the Group By in C# could you suggest me an idea about that? Thanks Please check my answer below @Greg

Comment: @user3520221 Can you be more specific?